# jquery focusout == submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I tell if the focusout event occured due to an enter press = form submit or just because of clicking away? The event data which goes to the console is of type "focusout" and has no relevant information

```
$(".clientrow[clientid="+clientid+"] td."+fieldname+"").bind("focusout", function(event){
    console.log(event);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!event.delegateTarget.contains(document.activeElement)) {
            $(".clientrow[clientid="+clientid+"] td."+fieldname+"").html( 
                    $(".clientrow[clientid="+clientid+"] td."+fieldname+" input[type=text]").val()
                );
            }
        }, 0);
    });
```

Comment: There is no way to tell __why__ a focusout event (officially known as a "blur" event) occurred. You might be able to listen out for preceding events, such as a "click" or "submit", hook your callback function in at that point and cancel the subsequent "blur" event. Maybe.

Comment: did you tried something similar like `ng-blur` directive

Comment: @KieranPotts [`blur`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-blur) and [`focusout`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-focusout) are different events, both standard.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As Oriol pointed in the comments, this will not work in Mozilla. If you are looking only for webkit browsers, you can try this approach. But as a generic solution, try binding an event on submit button and consecutively set a flag which identifies the element. Based on the element, you can detect whether it's an actual blur or not.

You can look out for `relatedTarget` property in the `event`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/782/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").on("blur", function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        if (e.relatedTarget) {
            console.log("Because of button");
        } else {
            console.log("Just a blur")
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You'll have to replace the `focusout` with `blur` event. When the blur is due to a click on a button, the relatedTarget property will have `button` as value but in other cases it will be null.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll check it out in a sec.

Comment: On Firefox I always get "Just a blur".

Comment: @RápliAndrás  Which version and OS?